# how to set limits to a number while increasing or decreasing it in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I want to increase a number when a specific condition is met and in the else part I want to decrease that number but this should be within the specified limit. Condition is like there is a time stamp of a whole day with the interval of 15mins, so there will be 96 total block for 24hours. Now when the time is between 6am to 7pm then the number should increase but up to a specific limit and when the time is between 7pm to next day 6am it should decrease. my code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
timeStamp = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2020' , end = '1/1/2020', freq = '15min')
num = 0
numLowerLimit = 0
numHigherLimit = 1
chargeTime = 6
dischargeTime = 19
for t in timeStamp:
   if chargeTime <= t.hour < dischargeTime:
        if numLowerLimit <= num <= numHigherLimit:
            num = num + 0.23
            print(num)
        else:
            num = 1
            print(num)
    else:
        if numLowerLimit <= num <= numHigherLimit:
            num = num - 0.23
            print(num)
        else:
            num = 0
            print(num)
```

error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

expected output:

```
2020-01-01 06:00:00' - 0.23
2020-01-01 06:15:00' - 0.46
2020-01-01 06:30:00' - 0.69
2020-01-01 06:45:00' - 0.92
2020-01-01 07:00:00' -  1
2020-01-01 07:15:00' -  1
2020-01-01 07:30:00' -  1
.
.
.
2020-01-01 19:00:00' -  1
2020-01-01 19:15:00' -  0.77
2020-01-01 19:30:00' -  0.54
2020-01-01 19:45:00' -  0.31
2020-01-01 20:00:00' -  0.54
2020-01-01 20:15:00' -  0.31
2020-01-01 20:30:00' -  0.08
2020-01-01 20:45:00' -  0
2020-01-01 20:00:00' -  0
```

Comment: can you add full traceback for error?

Comment: Are you running this exact code? It doesn't give an error when I try it.

Comment: i want the answer like this expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime
timeStamp = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2020 06:00:00' , end = '1/1/2020 23:59:00', freq = '15min')
num = 0
numLowerLimit = 0
numHigherLimit = 1
chargeTime = 6
dischargeTime = 19
for t in timeStamp:    
    num = min([num + 0.23, 1]) if chargeTime <= t.hour < dischargeTime else max([num - 0.23, 0])
    print(f'{t} {num:.2f}')
```